# Linear search to find spelling errors in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm working on learning Python with Program Arcade Games and I've gotten stuck on one of the labs.

I'm supposed to compare each word of a text file (http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/en/AliceInWonderLand200.txt) to find if it is not in the dictionary file (http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/en/dictionary.txt) and then print it out if it is not.  I am supposed to use a linear search for this.

The problem is even words I know are not in the dictionary file aren't being printed out.  Any help would be appreciated.

My code is as follows:

```
# Imports regular expressions
import re

# This function takes a line of text and returns
# a list of words in the line


def split_line(line):
    split = re.findall('[A-Za-z]+(?:\'\"[A-Za-z]+)?', line)
    return split


# Opens the dictionary text file and adds each line to an array, then closes the file
dictionary = open("dictionary.txt")
dict_array = []
for item in dictionary:
    dict_array.append(split_line(item))
print(dict_array)
dictionary.close()

print("---Linear Search---")

# Opens the text for the first chapter of Alice in Wonderland
chapter_1 = open("AliceInWonderland200.txt")

# Breaks down the text by line
for each_line in chapter_1:
    # Breaks down each line to a single word
    words = split_line(each_line)
    # Checks each word against the dictionary array
    for each_word in words:
        i = 0
        # Continues as long as there are more words in the dictionary and no match
        while i < len(dict_array) and each_word.upper() != dict_array[i]:
            i += 1
        # if no match was found print the word being checked
        if not i <= len(dict_array):
            print(each_word)

# Closes the first chapter file
chapter_1.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Linear search to find spelling errors in Python

Something like this should do (pseudo code)

```
sampleDict = {}
For each word in AliceInWonderLand200.txt:
    sampleDict[word] = True

actualWords = {}
For each word in dictionary.txt:
    actualWords[word] = True

For each word in sampleDict:
    if not (word in actualDict):
        # Oh no!  word isn't in the dictionary
```

A [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) may be more appropriate than a dict, since the value of the dictionary in the sample isn't important.  This should get you going, though

Comment: While that is basically what my code above does, my code didn't add the AliceInWonderLand200 text to a list.  

Making it do that got it to work properly.  Thanks.